# Simply change label text before long method

Tags: c#, asp.net

It is probably so simple, yet I can't figure it out. I have a simple contact form within an updatePanel, when the user presses the Send button, a label should appear before sending. When done it should say something like Message Send.

Application.DoEvents() would do the trick but yes, we are in asp.net...
I have tried multithread, but still the lblMessageSend text changes to "Sending e-mail.. Please Wait.." AFTER the message has been send. Besides that being not ThreadSafe as whatever, still doesn't work..

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessageSend.Text = "Sending e-mail.. Please Wait..";
    lblMessageSend.Visible = true;
    ThreadStart t1 = new ThreadStart(SendMessage);
    Thread thr = new Thread(t1);
    thr.Start(); 
}

private void SendMessage()
{
    //do some sending stuff
    lblMessageSend.Text = Resources.strings.quotationMessage;
}
```

html

```
</tr>
     <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" ValidationGroup="Form" TabIndex="12" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
    </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessageSend" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="<%$ Resources:strings, quotationMessage%>"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you can use javascript in this case, using onClientClick for the button to change the label text when pressing the button. Then in the method you can change the label text from code behind just like you did.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx @Black Baron.

```
         <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" ValidationGroup="Form" OnClientClick="ChangeLabelText();" TabIndex="12" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessageSend" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (Page_ClientValidate()) { //to check if the validationFields are validated..
                document.getElementById('<%= lblMessageSend.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'Sending.. Please wait..';
            }
</script>
```

To be honest, I am kind of disappointed by the fact that I still have to use javascript to get things done. But it works and that is important.

Comment: Only one problem still, when I have regular expression or field validators, it won't check for that first..